# Floating number calculation

Tags: php

I have two floats:

```
time1: 0.009925 
time2: 0.01
```

When I return `time1 - time2` I get this:

```
difference -7.5E-5
```

`time2 - time1` returns 7.5E-5 as well.

How do you return a normal float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try number_format https://www.php.net/number-format

```
echo number_format(0.009925 - 0.01,5); //-0.00008
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct answer to the computation, returned as a normal float value would do.

It's worth noting that the `E` refers to `x10^N`, so those values are equivalent to `7.5x10^-5`. I think your confusion stems from this.